# How to send float value in FreeMarker form (type number allows only integers)

Tags: html, freemarker

Good day. Could you help me solve my issue. I am struggling to send float value in Apache Free Marker form. I have type=number, but it allows only integers. If I change type to text i will loose checking for input values (instead digit user can send letters).

Thanks a lot.

Meters

Comment: You can use `input type="number" step="any"` for floating point numbers.

Comment: This is actually not related to FreeMarker at all.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.